# Android-How can i attach SQLite database in python app

Tags: android, python-3.x, sqlite, kivy

So i am writing a python3 app with kivy and i want to have some data stored in a database using sqlite.

The user needs to have access to that data from the first time he opens the app

Is there a way to possibly make it so that when i launch the app, the user that downloads it, will already have the data i stored, like distribute the database along with the app? so that i don't have to create it for every user.

I have searched here and there but haven't found an answer yet

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the database file in the apk, as you would any other file.

Comment: thank you! As you can tell, im really really new to programming and thus the (probably) stupid question